# Is it possible avrage power on resistor in circuit is zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electromagnetic-induction

Is it possible that if I have a current creat by magnetic field inductance, I will get that the average power that consume to heat on a resistor is zero?

and if yes what does it mean?

Comment: Since the instantaneous resistor power is $p_R(t)=Ri_R^2(t)$, I don't see how the average power can be zero unless $i_R(t)=0$. Have I misunderstood your question? It's not quite clear to me what you're thinking about. Are you thinking about the reactive power of an inductor (which has time average zero)?

Comment: Yes, If I have a situation that my ECM is a period function of $sin$ than I get that my current is also function of $sin$ and if I calculate avarage power I get the result zero